# CLUSTER requires more space than expected

Tags: postgresql

I have a very large table with a GIST index on a Postgis geometry column, `540GB` and `300GB` in size respectively. There are no other contraints or indecies on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    version int NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    tstamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    changeset_id bigint NOT NULL,
    tags hstore,
    geom geometry(Point,4326)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_nodes_geom ON nodes USING gist (geom);
```

Need to cluster the table using the geom index.

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-cluster.html) say

> When an index scan is used, a temporary copy of the table is created
>   that contains the table data in the index order. Temporary copies of
>   each index on the table are created as well. Therefore, you need free
>   space on disk at least equal to the sum of the table size and the
>   index sizes.

I have `900GB` of free space, so expect it to be enough, but it fails with `no space left on device` error.

What am I missing here please?

Comment: Do you know that it is using an index scan, rather than a sort?

Comment: Sequencial scan is used for b-tree indecies, so yes, I assume it is using index scan in my case.

Comment: That seems like a bad assumption.  Why would btree using the seq scan mean something else would not?  If anything it would be the opposite, if even btree uses a seq scan, why wouldn't gist?

Comment: I've tried setting `enable_sort=off` but still ended up with `No space left on device`.

Comment: Where is the space being used?  Is there anything in $PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp ?

Comment: It is writing to `base` subfolders but `base/pgsql_tmp` is empty.